# Make marker fixed to centre of screen, while the map moves; Then update the current location of marker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using `@agm/core` to display maps on an angular ui, I can place the markers on the map, and can make it draggable via `[mapDraggable]` set to `true`.

The problem is i need the marker to stay at centre of screen while the map in the background moves, I need to update the latest location of the marker and store them in variables.

I tried using CSS but couldn't, Here is the code i'm using.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [mapDraggable]="true" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="zoom">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [markerDraggable]="false" (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(marker, $event)"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

The CSS used is like this

```
agm-map {
    height: 100vh;
}

agm-marker {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50vw;
    top: 50vh;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Using the above code the map is draggable but the marker moves with the map, How do i make the map draggable while the marker stays at centre of screen. I need the updated latitude and longitude of the marker.

Comment: Please refer to this SO answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/36723757/4112088

Comment: Thanks. Will look into it.

Comment: Hey @Nithin, did you solve it?