# Google Maps V2: Does rotating the map change the orientation of TileOverlays?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2

Background: I want to draw several Polygons on a map (few thousand coordinates in all). This worked pretty fast on Google Maps V1 by Overlays. But Google Maps V2 seems to be ineligible for that.
First of all I tried to add polygons directly to the map by

```
googleMap.addPolygon(myPolygonOptions);
```

but this is not just unusable slow, it seems to be buggy too, because it always forgets some polygons.
Then I tried to draw the polygon on an invisible view placed above the map, by drawing paths. But the method

```
projection.toScreenLocation(geoCoordinate);
```

is a joke to its "toPixels" Google Maps V1 counterpart. Where Google Maps V1 takes 1 second, Google Maps V2 takes 21(!) seconds, so this is unusable too.

Then I thought about giving Overlays a try. [Ground overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/groundoverlay) seems to be what I'm looking for:

> A ground overlay is an image that is fixed to a map. Unlike markers,
>   ground overlays are oriented against the Earth's surface rather than
>   the screen, so rotating, tilting or zooming the map will change the
>   orientation of the image. Ground overlays are useful when you wish to
>   fix a single image at one area on the map.

But then I read a comment in [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105531/what-is-the-suggested-way-of-implementing-overlays-in-v2-of-the-android-google-m) that it is not performant too and doesn't even work well.

So the last hope are [Tile Overlays](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay). The question is: What happens with tile overlays when I rotate the map. Do they change their orientation too or will they stay oriented as loaded?

**[UPDATE]**
I tried GroundOverlays and they are pretty fast, even on old Smartphones, so I will choose this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tile will be rotated together with the map. The TileProvider will not get aware of the rotation at all. While drawing the tile is always oriented north up. You may have a look at the answer to this SO question for a very handy tile provider: [Google Maps API v2 draw part of circle on MapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20382823/google-maps-api-v2-draw-part-of-circle-on-mapfragment/20408460#20408460)